# Вводное сочетание и определение в конце предложения

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, определения

*Впереди них стоял еще один охранник, судя по всему(?) главный.*

Правильно ли я понимаю, что запятая не ставится, т. к. "главный" рассматривается как обособленное дополнение, а от вводного сочетания при таком построении предложения оно не отделяется?

Comment: Александр, думаю, что "главный" —  это определение, а не дополнение.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Да, наверное, сглупил... Но пунктуация верна? Запятую не ставим?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что о такой ситуации сказано в ПАС (под ред. Лопатина):

> § 93. Если вводное слово или вводное сочетание слов стоит в начале или в конце обособленного члена предложения, то оно не отделяется от него знаком препинания, т. е. запятые выделяют член предложения вместе с вводным словом...

Вот что — у Розенталя:

> **4.** Если вводное слово (сочетание) стоит в начале или в конце обособленного оборота (обособления, уточнения, пояснения, присоединения), то никаким знаком препинания от оборота оно не отделяется...

И приведены примеры, схожие с нашим: *Вечер сегодня будет по-осеннему серый, **наверно ненастный**; Это исключительно благоприятный случай, **по сути дела единственный**; Для анализа были предложены тексты, **как правило нетрудные**; Он весьма бережливый человек, **можно даже сказать — скуповатый*** (постановка тире факультативна).

Правильно понимаете: запятую не ставим (но тире — вполне возможно).
*Впереди них стоял ещё один охранник, судя по всему главный.*

Для сравнения (вводное слово выделено запятыми, так как находится **внутри** обособленного оборота):
Помимо возможности устраивать маленькие кулинарные праздники, в таком ведении хозяйства был еще один плюс, *самый, **пожалуй,** главный.* [Александра Маринина. Стечение обстоятельств (1992)]

[Знаки препинания при вводных словах, сочетаниях слов и предложениях](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=127#pp127)
 [Вводные слова и словосочетания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=121#pp121)